# How to add content to a file before the last } character using Busybox utilities?

Tags: awk, sed, grep, json, busybox

There is a file with contents

```
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "is_alive": true,
  "age": 27,
  "address": {
    "street_address": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postal_code": "10021-3100"
  },
  "phone_numbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    }
  ],
  "children": [
    "Catherine",
    "Thomas",
    "Trevor"
  ],
  "spouse": null
}
```

How to add content to a file before the last } character using Busybox utilities so that the file content becomes like below?

```
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "is_alive": true,
  "age": 27,
  "address": {
    "street_address": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postal_code": "10021-3100"
  },
  "phone_numbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    }
  ],
  "children": [
    "Catherine",
    "Thomas",
    "Trevor"
  ],
  "spouse": null,
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "field3": "value3",
  "field4": "value4"
}
```

However, the } character is not necessarily the last character in the file and is not necessarily located on the last line.

So far I have found only this solution

```
tac file2 | sed '0,/}/s/}/}\n"field4": "value4"\n"field3": "value3",\n"field2": "value2",\n"field1": "value1",\n,/' | tac>tmp_file && mv tmp_file file2
```

Comment: @ilkkachu not, only after the last } in file

Comment: @ilkkachu yes I was wrong

Comment: Is the data guaranteed to already be a valid JSON string?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes the data is a valid json string

Comment: Good answer, spending time figure it out, no edit from others. Looks good enough ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any awk and any bourne-like shell:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

new='\
"field1": "value1",
"field2": "value2",
"field3": "value3",
"field4": "value4"\
'

awk '
    { lines[NR] = $0 }
    $0 == "}" { last = NR - 1 }
    END {
        for ( i=1; i<last; i++ ) {
            print lines[i]
        }
        print lines[i] ","

        indent = lines[i]
        sub(/[^ \t].*/,"",indent)
        gsub(/(^|\n)/,"&"indent,new)
        print new

        for ( ++i; i<=NR; i++ ) {
            print lines[i]
        }
    }
' new="$new" file
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "is_alive": true,
  "age": 27,
  "address": {
    "street_address": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postal_code": "10021-3100"
  },
  "phone_numbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    }
  ],
  "children": [
    "Catherine",
    "Thomas",
    "Trevor"
  ],
  "spouse": null,
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "field3": "value3",
  "field4": "value4"
}
```

Note that it sets the indent for the new block to be whatever the indent is for the line immediately before it so you don't have to hard-code that indent and it'll work even if you have lines of comments or blank lines after the last `}` line.

Comment: Works great, but how can I make sure that if a file matches the pattern \s*{\s*}\s*, there is no comma displayed before the added text?

Comment: @Maxim I'm not sure what you mean by that comment. Accept an answer to this question you asked and then ask a new question if you can't figure out how to do whatever else it is you want to do since [Chameleon Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged.

Comment: Why not using the more portable `-v variable` ? And there's no here-documents in your post.

Comment: Indent levels don't matter for JSON, and neither should key ordering. So it ought to be perfectly ok to add the data just after the initial curly brace too. Well, assuming you implement proper JSON processing in Awk.

Comment: @GillesQuénot `-v` isn't more portable than assigning a variable in the args list, it just makes that variables value available in the BEGIN section, which I'm not using, but it also interprets escape sequences so you can't use `-v` to pass literal strings into awk and idk what characters the real `new` string might contain. I removed the mention of here-docs, thanks.

Comment: @Kusalananda since the OP is asking how to modify this data without a JSON-aware tool, I don't think we can assume that the other tool they already have that reads this data is JSON-aware. When developing software that has to exchange data you have to pick SOME format to do so and it's not unusual to settle on some subset of JSON or CSV and use tools to read/write that subset without having to implement a full parser for that format. So, though the OP has told us their data is JSON, I don't assume they can use anything other than the indent+order+tags subset they've shown us, unrelated to awk.

Comment: Hmm... If they don't use a JSON parser to read the data at some point, what's the actual use of storing the data in JSON at all? It would be easier to use a line-oriented format like a simple tab-delimited file (or CSV which you mention).  If they do use a JSON parser, _then_ indentation and key ordering does definitely not matter.

Comment: As I'm sure you know, it's clumsy to define structured data with a CSV (you end up with multiple duplicate values and/or many rows of mostly empty cells and/or large numbers of columns for every possible tag) so the most obvious alternative is JSON and it's not hard to write a parser for a defined subset of JSON. If they had a full JSON parser then I expect they'd ask how to do this job using it.

Comment: I spent 30+ years working on a product that only supported POSIX tools. We used CSV a lot and never once had or wrote a full CSV parser, we just exchanged data without embedded commas, quotes, or newlines in the fields. Its not outrageous to pick some subset of some well-known format to use in your product and just use that since you have to use **something** and at least then you can copy files off the product if/when necessary (e.g. for debugging) and use industry-available tools to view it.

Comment: and if I did write a tool to parse some format I define that is a subset of JSON (and so could be interpreted by external tools) then maybe I'd decide that indentation does matter for my format, e.g. to make parsing easier in some way, just like the python people decided to make indentation meaningful for their code despite it looking like most other Algol-based languages otherwise. Basically, I'm just not making any assumptions about what might be valid for their data and/or what other tools they may have available and just giving the OP what they asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `ed` utility (tested in a `BusyBox` container):

```
ed file<<EOF
$ i
  ,
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "field3": "value3",
  "field4": "value4"
.
w
q
EOF
cat file
```

The output file pass the [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) test.

Comment: Only works if } is on the last line

Comment: Yes, that's the case in your sample input ^^

Answer (score 2):

If the last } is the last line then this can be done with head command.
Include the last } in your added text:

```
$ cat addit
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "field3": "value3",
  "field4": "value4"
}
```

And what you want is:

```
$ (head -n -1 input_file ;cat addit)
```

You leave out the last } from your added text and instead pipe the above output to this sed:

```
$ sed '$ a \}'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are very confident that the file ends with `}\n` (or just `}` no newline at end of file), you could `truncate` the last 2 bytes (or 1 byte). Use `tail -c` to verify beforehand.

After `truncate`, the file would be missing the last `}` but be otherwise intact. At this point simply `>>` append new text (including the `}` you truncated).

Unfortunately, busybox `truncate` does not understand relative sizes (`-2`) so you need to do the math yourself and use `stat -c %s` to determine the size in bytes.

This method would also work with very large files, without needing to read all the contents first. `awk`, `ed`, `head -n`, etc. all read the entire file.

Comment: The } character is not necessarily the last character in the file; it may be followed by whitespace and newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer does not restrict itself to using only utilities built into the Busybox multi-binary but uses [the `jq` utility](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/). This well-known JSON processing tool is available as a static binary for most common architectures, requiring no escalation of permission to install or use.  You can also use it via a public Docker image.

Since Busybox multi-binaries may contain a wildly varying number of built-in utilities, depending on exactly what Busybox is being used (302 utilities on Alpine Linux, but an additional 100 extra in the public Busybox Docker image), and since this was not mentioned in the question, I'm assuming that the restriction is purely artificial and not terribly important.

---

Once you have installed `jq` you may use it in different ways to add your data, depending on in what form you provide the new data.

Assuming separate keys and unencoded strings, you would use `jq` with `--arg key value` to encode each string and create internal `jq` variables.  For values that are already appropriately encoded (numbers, booleans, JSON strings, or JSON fragments) use `--argjson` instead of `--arg`.  You may then use the key names prepended by `$` (`$key1`, `$var2`, `$lastname` etc.) inside the `jq` expression to access the individual pieces of data, or you may access all such variables using the special `$ARGS.named` object:

```bash
jq  --arg field1 value1 \
    --arg field2 'value2 ("temporarily")' \
    --arg field3 value3 \
    --argjson field4 true \
    --argjson field5 '{ "some json fragment": [ "goes", "here" ] }' \
    '. += $ARGS.named' file.json
```

With your first example document in `file.json`, this would produce the following:

```json
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "is_alive": true,
  "age": 27,
  "address": {
    "street_address": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postal_code": "10021-3100"
  },
  "phone_numbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    }
  ],
  "children": [
    "Catherine",
    "Thomas",
    "Trevor"
  ],
  "spouse": null,
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2 (\"temporarily\")",
  "field3": "value3",
  "field4": true,
  "field5": {
    "some json fragment": [
      "goes",
      "here"
    ]
  }
}
```

You may obviously decide where the data is inserted in the document by specifying a path different from `.` in the expression above.  For example, to add the data to any input object that represents a person who has at least one home phone number starting with "212":

```
select(
    .phone_numbers |
    map(.type == "home" and (.number | startswith("212"))) |
    any
) += $ARGS.named
```

Comment: Upvoted. `jq` is the real thing for this kind of files.