# How to check the contents of an entire file against the pattern \s*{\s*}\s*?

Tags: text-processing, json, busybox

How to check the contents of an entire file for compliance with the pattern `\s*{\s*}\s*` using busybox? You need to check the entire file from beginning to end, and not individual lines, as `grep` does.

Required to detect whether a file contains an empty JSON object, for example in the general case:

```json
   
   { 

  }
```

Below is an example of file content that does not meet the template requirements.

```json
{
"field": {}
}

{}
   
   { 

  }
```

Comment: [Your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/771937/116858) was about editing a JSON file using busybox only. Are you now trying to validate the structure of a JSON file without the proper tools? I believe you would be better served by just installing a JSON parser, or you would need to implement one yourself.  Note that you also have to cope with _strings_ that are valid and invalid JSON documents.

Comment: Please explain, in English words and sentences, what you want to do. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Note that your regex, assuming you expect us to interpret that as a PCRE where `\s` matches whitespace, would match a file whose contents are nothing but one line with `{}`. Is that _really_ what you want?

Comment: @Kusalananda there is no way to install anything on the target platform

Comment: A completely different approach: create once the md5sum and compare it with md5sum of your current file?

Comment: If your need is just to verify a coding process that runs inside of busybox (but will not be required as part of the busybox system), then can you `ssh` (or `scp`) to your busybox machine, retrieve the file and do your validation on an external machine that has proper software available?

Comment: @terdon no, I was wrong, I tried to analyze it line by line using grep.

Comment: @Cyrus no, files can contain different numbers of spaces and line breaks, but be identical in content.

Comment: @shellter no, the script must be executed automatically on the device.

Comment: Hold on. If there's no way to install anything on the target platform, then how would you run any of the answers here?  The jq utility could be copied as a static binary to any directory on the system and run from there. You seem to create artificial difficulties for yourself.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, there are restrictions on the software used, that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: @Maxim So you can _write_, transfer, and install any executable you want (e.g. a script), but you can't do the same with any static executable? I'm assuming there's a process for getting your own software approved for installation on this super secret system? If there is, then you should also let `jq` go through that process.  I would trust `jq` to read and write JSON infinitely more than I would trust any piece of code _anyone_ wrote here to do the same thing.  I mean, come on, validating a structured document format using _regular expressions_?

Comment: Also note that the regular expression that you propose can only be interpreted as a valid regular expression if it's a _basic_ POSIX expression.  The unescaped `{` and `}` with `\s*` in-between means it's not a valid extended POSIX expression, nor a Perl-compatible expression (PCRE).  As a basic POSIX expression, it would match e.g. `sss{ss}s`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I agree, it looks suspect and would be better with a backslash. But Perl seems to accept it anyway, e.g. `echo '{ }' | perl -ne 'print if /\s*{\s*}\s*/'` matches and prints the line (Ubuntu 22.04, Perl v5.34.0). If I try e.g. `/\s{/`, it complains about the unescaped left brace, but I suppose it accepts it in `/\s*{/`, since the `*` already acts as a qualifier, so `{` can't be another. It does complain about a nested qualifier for `/\s*{2}/`, though.

Comment: Speaking of Perl, matching a whole file against a Perl RE would be easily done in Perl. But the Q says "using busybox", and that might be a rather hard limitation. Does Busybox even have anything that understands Perl REs? If the environment is very limited (in storage), it might not have Perl, but if it happens to have it, there's also a JSON module for Perl, in case you want to actually parse the file as a JSON document. (`jq` is fine too, of course.)

Comment: n your question you say "check", "detect", and "distinguish" but you never say what to **do** if the file matches the regexp you want to check/detect/distinguish. You say "it is necessary to distinguish when there are several json objects in the file" but you don't say why it's necessary - before that it seemed like you wanted to match the whole file contents against your regexp but is that not the case? Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and provide concise, testable sample input **and the associated expected output for each input case** that covers all of your use cases

Answer (score 2):

> How to check the contents of an entire file for compliance with the pattern `\s*{\s*}\s*` using busybox?

To answer this literally, without regard for the surrounding questions about processing JSON files in general...

The first thing I'm wondering is if Busybox has anything that supports Perl regexes. But no matter, even if `\s` couldn't be used, the POSIX RE equivalent for `\s` is `[[:space:]]*`. (Though Busybox seems to accept `\s` too, at least on my Linux.)

As for matching against the whole file and not a single line, Busybox's grep might have the `-z` option for using NUL instead of the newline as a "line" terminator. It depends on the `CONFIG_EXTRA_COMPAT` compile-time option, which appears to be set my Ubuntu 22.04, but YMMV. Since your text file shouldn't contain any NULs, that should do to match against the whole file.

I'm also assuming that when you say to "check the entire file from beginning to end", you mean that the pattern should be locked to the start and end of the file, and it should not be enough to find a match somewhere in the middle of the file. Regex engines usually look for matches anywhere, and you need to explicitly use the `^`/`$` anchors to lock the pattern at the start/end.

So:

```
$ printf '   \t \n   {  \n\t  \n } \n \n\n' > test1
$ cat test1

   {

 }


$ busybox grep -qz '^[[:space:]]*{[[:space:]]*}[[:space:]]*$' test1 && echo match
match
```

Comment: Busybox's `grep` seems to interpret `\s` as if it was PCRE (both with and without `-E`).

Comment: @Kusalananda, oh, right, that's what the GNU one also does, at least on my Linuxen. `\w` also works, but `\d` doesn't. It's so arbitrary.

Comment: And hmmm... The Busybox on Alpine Linux (or the `busybox:latest` Docker image) does not seem to have `grep -z`.  Maybe it depends on the distribution's setup of Busybox, or on Busybox version?

Comment: @Kusalananda, argh. It might even be a compile-time option for all I know. I can't see anything immediately obvious on the changelog in https://www.busybox.net and I'm not sure I'll bother to look more deeply into it. :)

Comment: @Kusalananda, well, I checked anyway, it's CONFIG_EXTRA_COMPAT, "Provide compatible behavior for rare corner cases (bigger code)": "This option makes grep, sed etc handle rare corner cases (embedded NUL bytes and such). [...]"

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer does not restrict itself to using only utilities built into the Busybox multi-binary but uses [the `jq` utility](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/). This well-known JSON processing tool is available as a static binary for most common architectures, requiring no escalation of permission to install or use.  You can also use it via a public Docker image.

---

Once you have installed `jq`, you can use the following command to determine whether a JSON document has any empty objects anywhere:

```bash
jq '.. | select(type == "object" and (keys | length == 0) and halt_error)' file.json
```

This recurses through the whole input object(s) and halts with a non-zero exit status at the first empty object it finds.  An "empty object" is an object with no keys.

Example:

```bash
$ cat file1
{"hello":{"string":"{}"}}
$ cat file1 | if jq '.. | select(type == "object" and (keys | length == 0) and halt_error)' 2>/dev/null; then echo 'contains no empty object(s)'; else echo 'contains empty object(s)'; fi
contains no empty object(s)
```

```bash
$ cat file2
{"hello":{"not a string":{}}}
$ cat file2 | if jq '.. | select(type == "object" and (keys | length == 0) and halt_error)' 2>/dev/null; then echo 'contains no empty object(s)'; else echo 'contains empty object(s)'; fi
contains empty object(s)
```

---

Alternative to the above `jq` expression is the following that applies the same logical evaluation to each part of the input document, but using `walk()` in place of `..` and `select()`:

```
walk(type == "object" and (keys | length == 0) and halt_error)
```

---

To get the specific paths in your input that have empty objects, you may use `paths()` like so:

```
paths(type == "object" and (keys | length == 0))
```

For the second of my example inputs above, this would return the following path array:

```json
[
  "hello",
  "not a string"
]
```

Note that this would not return anything if there are top-level empty objects, but you could combine it with the expression at the start of this answer to identify these.

Comment: While this answer is not technically answering the question, it is providing the correct approach and it is the question itself that needs to be revised. Perhaps that should be included in this answer.

Comment: @Vilinkameni I'll write an introductory note to the answer. Thanks for the poke.

Answer (score 1):

Could be:

```
if
  expr "@$(cat <file.json)" : '@[[:space:]]*{[[:space:]]*}[[:space:]]*$' > /dev/null
then
  echo is an empty JSON object
fi
```

Comment: Why `expr "@$(cat <file.json)" : '@[[:space:]]...` instead of `expr "$(cat <file.json)" : '^[[:space:]]...` (added `@`s at start of string+regexp instead of only start-of-string anchor `^` in regexp).

Comment: @EdMorton see for instance [Unix shell : substring with regular expression](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/513151) or [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/expr.html#tag_20_42_17) (`expr` is mostly broken by design)

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. I think I've used `expr` this way once in the past 40+ years so I didn't know about that little gem!

Answer (score 0):

If you were going to rely on GNU tools you could just use GNU grep:

```
$ grep -zq '^\s*{\s*}\s*$' file && echo "found"
found
```

Otherwise using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk '
    { rec = ( NR>1 ? rec RS : "" ) $0 }
    END {
        print ( rec ~ /^[[:space:]]*[{][[:space:]]*}[[:space:]]*$/ ? "" : "not " ) "found"
    }
' file
found
```

If you don't have a POSIX awk for the `[:space:]` character class then change each `[[:space:]]` to `[ \t\n]` or whatever list of "space" chars your file can contain.

The above were run on this input file:

```
$ cat file

   {

  }
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to remove all line breaks and spaces and then check if the string matches the pattern.

```
{ tr -d '[:space:]' < file; printf '\n'; } | grep -Fxc '{}'
```

Comment: Note that this would still fail to detect internal empty objects if the original JSON is presented as a single line. Removing the -x option would then also detect {} embedded in strings.

Comment: `tr -d '[:space:]' < file` would convert your input into something that is no longer a valid text file (text files must end with a newline to be valid) and than you're passing it to a text-processing tool (grep) that's only required to be able to process valid text files and so what grep does with that input is undefined behavior and so YMMV today or in future versions of grep.

Comment: @EdMorton `echo $(tr -d '[:space:]' < file) | grep -Fxc '{}'` will this be the correct file?

Comment: No, that's much worse as it exposes the output of `tr` unquoted to the shell for globbing and filename expansion, will additionally fail if that output starts with `-`, and will do different things with escape chars depending on which version of `echo` is picked up.

Comment: If you REALLY wanted to do this for some reason then you'd have to make it `{ tr -d '[:space:]' < file; printf '\n'; } | grep -Fxc '{}'` to be portable to all POSIX tool versions.